# .htaccess file does not load js and css

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

I was trying a MVC tutorial by howcode on youtube but found that htaccess does not allow my css and js files to load.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried to find some solutions over the internet but end up generating other errors. I used conditions before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Project Structure -

I have these files in project

1. Classes (folder)
2. Controller (folder)
3. Views (folder)
4. .htaccess
5. index.php
6. Routes.php

In Views folder I have-

1. css (folder)
2. js (folder)
3. index.php
4. header.php
5. footer.php

My all the imports are in header.php and header.php is included in index.php

My code for linking css is-

```
<link href="./Views/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
```

Comment: Are you using codeigniter?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman no, I am not using codeigniter or any other framework

Comment: Check your network tab in your browser's dev tools. What are the return codes for the CSS/JS files? Are the path's correct? (this is *with* the `RewriteCond`

Comment: @JonLin It is not showing any path errors but it is showing that MIME type of css file text/html rather than text/css. I don't think that it is an issue because it is working fine without htaccess

Answer (score 2):

> I used conditions before the rule:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> ```

That *condition* is the opposite of what you are trying to achieve - the logic is reversed. That condition tests if the file exists and only if it exists then process the `RewriteRule`. You need the rule to execute only when the requested file does *not* exist. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note the `!` prefix on the *CondPattern*. This *negates* the condition.

---

**UPDATE:** Note that the above `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^([^/]+)/?`) excludes requests for the document root (ie. `http://example.com/` - an *empty* URL-path). So, the `url` GET parameter will indeed be *undefined* in your PHP script for this request. However, this should be OK, providing you are checking the existence of this variable before using it (as you should be). For example:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
```

If you explicitly want this parameter to be set (and your directive processed) for such requests (although unnecessary) then you would need to change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^([^/]+)/?` to `^([^/]*)/?`, ie. change `+` (1 or more) to `*` (0 or more).

Comment: I used this but it gave me error in php that "Undefined index: url"

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Using the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ in your question, `url` won't be set if you request the document root ie. `http://example.com/`, but should be OK if requesting a positive URL-path, ie. `http://example.com/something`. If you specifically need this to match the document root (although unnecessary) you can change the pattern from `^([^/]+)/?` to `^([^/]*)/?` (ie. change `+` for `*`). However, this highlights a bug in your PHP code: you should always check the existence of a URL `$_GET` parameter before using it.

Comment: It did not worked. Now it is not giving any errors but still no css

Comment: How are you referencing your CSS files in index.php? What URL are you using?

Comment: And what URL are you requesting?

Comment: And what is a typical URL you are requesting? Your `RewriteRule` directive only matches the first path segment, so would only work for URLs of the form `/file`, not `/path/to/file`. If you directly request a CSS file eg. `/Views/css/style.css`? Since this file presumably exists, it won't be processed by the above directives. Why are you starting your URL paths `./` (with a dot)? That makes the path _relative_ and will cause problems if you are URL rewriting.

Comment: I am requesting 'localhost/testmvc/'

Comment: I tried and removed './' (dot)  from it but still no result. I don't know that it will help or not but I checked the console,  it is showing that mime type of style.css is text/html rather than text/css. I dont think this is the problem because it is running fine without htaccess